# prime factorization in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

A "green" integer can be divided by 2 an even number of   times.
In   other   words,   there   is  an   even   number   of   2s   in   the   number's   prime factorization.

examples:

•80 is green because it can be divided by 2 exactly four times, and four is even.
(80 = 2*2*2*2*5, and 5 isn't divisible by 2)

•56 is not green because it can be divided by 2 exactly three times, and three is odd
  (56 = 2*2*2*7, and 7 isn't divisible by 2)

•15 is green because it can be divided by 2 zero times, and zero is even

I spent quite a lot time of this and the solution is suprisingly concise:

```
green 0 = error "zero"
green x
    | mod x 2 == 0 = not (green (div x 2))
    | mod x 2 == 1 = True
```

I can't figure the purpose of the "not (green (div x 2))" part.

Comment: If x is green, 2x is not, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
green x = go x 0
       where go 0 n = even n
             go x n | mod x 2 == 0 = go (div x 2) (n+1)
                    | otherwise    = even n


> zip [1..] $ map green [1..16]

[(1,True),(2,False),(3,True),(4,True),(5,True),(6,False),(7,True),(8,False),(9,True),
 (10,False),(11,True),(12,True),(13,True),(14,False),(15,True),(16,True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is divisible by 2 n times then `mod x 2` is divisible by 2 n-1 times, what are we trying to figure out is if n is even.
If `x` is a green number then `mod x 2` is not because if n is even then n-1 is odd.
If `x` is not a green number then `mod x 2` is a green number because if n is odd then n-1 is even.
This recurrence relation is enough, you don't need to know n, you only need to know if n is even, so this "not" does the switching between is n even or is not.